# Hide and unhide a specific shipping methods based on shipping class in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

i have a cart that has three method standard delivery(0-10kg), standard delivery(11-20kg) and next day delivery(0-20kg), my problem is when i a product with a frozen food shipping class to the cart the shipping method should only be the next day delivery and if there is now shipping class on the cart it only has the standard delivery, my problem is when a add the product with a shipping class and a products with no shipping class it will not go to the condition that i make.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function custom_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item  ) {
        $product = $cart_item[ 'data' ]; // The WC_Product object
        if( $product->get_shipping_class_id() == 149 ) { // <== ID OF MY SHIPPING_CLASS
            unset( $rates['shipping_by_rules:16'] ); // standard delivery
             wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '1', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ), 'error' );
        }else if($product->get_shipping_class_id() == NULL){
            unset( $rates['shipping_by_rules:15'] ); // next day delivery
             wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '2', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ), 'error' );
        }else if($product->get_shipping_class_id() !=  || $product->get_shipping_class_id() == 149){
            unset( $rates['shipping_by_rules:16'] ); // standard delivery
             wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '3', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ), 'error' );
        }
        break; // we stop the loop
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: sorry about that the code on the third is this 
else if($product->get_shipping_class_id() == NULL || $product->get_shipping_class_id() == 149)

Comment: This 3rd condition will never works… as you are taking 1st and 2nd

Comment: cause when i add an item with a shipping class and with no shipping class it will not go to the third conditon

Comment: what should i do? please help

Comment: what condition should i put if there is a products with a shipping class and no shipping in my cart, that will displat the next day delivery?

Comment: okay thank you so much

Comment: I have updated (2) my code… test it and let me know if it works (as I can't really test it myself) … But you are talking about 3 shipping methods and There is only 2 in your code so you should update your code with the 3rd shipping method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated 2:** There are many errors and mistakes in your code…

> THERE IS A MISSING SHIPPING METHOD IN YOUR CODE as you only have 2:
>
> - `'shipping_by_rules:16'` ==> Standard delivery(0-10kg)
> - `'shipping_by_rules:15'` ==> Next day delivery
>
> But what about **standard delivery(11-20kg)**

You should try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_hide_shipping_methods', 20, 2 );
function custom_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    $targeted_class_id = 149;  // <== ID OF MY SHIPPING_CLASS
    $has_class = $has_no_class = false;
    
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item  ) {
        $shipping_class = $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id();
        # $weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight();
        
        if( $shipping_class == $targeted_class_id ) 
            $has_class = true;
        elseif( empty( $shipping_class ) )
            $has_no_class = true;
    }
    // Unseting shipping methods
    if( $has_class ) 
    { // CASE 1 and 3
        unset( $rates['shipping_by_rules:16'] ); // standard delivery
        # wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '1 | %s', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ), 'error' );
    }
    elseif( ! $has_class && $has_no_class )
    { // CASE 2
        unset( $rates['shipping_by_rules:15'] ); // next day delivery
        # wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '2 | %s', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ), 'error' );
    }
    elseif( $has_class && $has_no_class ) // ==> Optional (You may not neeed it)
    { // CASE 3
        unset( $rates['shipping_by_rules:16'] ); // standard delivery
        # wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '3 | %s', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ), 'error' );
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

It should works.

Comment: thank you so much, reply appreciate it, the code works perfectly

Comment: why if i remove this code 
wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '2 | %s', 'woocommerce' ), $weight ), 'error' );
it wont work
can i remove this code?

Comment: cause i just added that so i could see what condition did it go, how can i remove that code but still making it work?

Comment: @MarvynSue Thanks … You can even get the total cart weight and interact on shipping methods too… Thinking about your 2 standard delivery methods (0-10kg) and (11-20kg)…